# selecting all rows from a database using JPA  in WebSphere

Tags: websphere, jpa-2.0, openjpa

I am trying to implement a web service that uses open JPA to access the data layer.  I am using websphere v7.0 and JPA 2.0.  This service is going to get all rows out of a small db (about 6 rows and it won't expand much at all in the future).  I am attempting to get all rows and return them through the user.  I am right now creating the Session Bean that will retrieve the data.

I have several JPA objects one of them (representing a row of all the data I want to return) looks like so...

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name="EmailDomainTrust.getEmailDomains",
        query="SELECT DOMAIN_NAME,"+ 
        "DESCRIPTION, CONFIRMED_BY, CONFIRMED_DATE" + 
        "FROM EMAIL_DOMAIN_TRUST")          
})
@Table(name="EMAIL_DOMAIN_TRUST")
public class EmailDomainTrust implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name="EMAIL_DOMAIN_TRUST_ID")
    private long emailDomainTrustId;

    @Column(name="DOMAIN_NAME")
    private String domainName;
}
```

There is a lot more in there, but I don't want to make this too long.  I just thought I would show a couple usefull  variables and maybe some get sets.
In my session bean I am trying to get all the rows...

```
public List<EmailDomainTrust> GetEmailDomains(){
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    //EntityTransaction userTransaction = em.getTransaction();
    System.out.println("Testing 1..2...3...!");
    List<EmailDomainTrust> ListOfEmailDomains = em.find(EmailDomainTrust.class, arg1)

    try
    {
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
    }
    return null;    
}
```

What I have so far is definitely not up to snuff.  But the tutorials online never describe getting all rows out of a table.  I won't have any parameters for this method, so I won't be able to select based on ID or anything like that.  Any advice would be great.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use `NamedQuery`

```
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name="EmailDomainTrust.getEmailDomains",
    query="SELECT e FROM EmailDomainTrust e")          
})
```

in  session bean:

```
return em.createNamedQuery("EmailDomainTrust.getEmailDomains", EmailDomainTrust.class).getResultList();
```

Comment: Or you can directly use the query string (example from [here](http://www.codemiles.com/jpa/get-all-objects-for-an-entity-t6273.html)).

`List<EmailDomainTrust> ListOfEmailDomains = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT e FROM EmailDomainTrust e").getResultList();`

Answer (score 17):

By inline query

```
List<EmailDomainTrust> ListOfEmailDomains = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT e FROM EmailDomainTrust e").getResultList();
```

By named query (by [Andrey and mprabhat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9793252/selecting-all-rows-from-a-database-using-jpa-in-websphere/9799384#9799384))

> You can use `NamedQuery`
>
> ```
> @NamedQueries({
> @NamedQuery(name="EmailDomainTrust.getEmailDomains",
>     query="SELECT e FROM EmailDomainTrust e")          
> })
> ```
>
> in  session bean:
>
> ```
> return em.createNamedQuery("EmailDomainTrust.getEmailDomains", EmailDomainTrust.class).getResultList();
> ```

With the query API (gleaned from [Criteria Query API](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/criteria#First_JPA_Criteria_Query_))

```
CriteriaQuery<EmailDomainTrust> criteria = em.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery(EmailDomainTrust.class);
    criteria.select(criteria.from(EmailDomainTrust.class));
    List<EmailDomainTrust> ListOfEmailDomains = em.createQuery(criteria).getResultList();
    return ListOfEmailDomains;
```