# Select * from table using jpa criteria not working properly

Tags: java, jpa

I'm using jpa criteria for my select clause. I'm not able to get the result set. Here is my code

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Object[]> cq = cb.createQuery(Object[].class);
Root<PKEntity> root = cq.from(PKEntity.class);
List<Object[]> resultlist = em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
```

It throws the following error

```
No terms is selected for criteria query. Use CriteriaQuery.select or multiselect.
```

What I'm doing wrong here? I'm using my mobile to post.. so I'm sorry I could nt post the whole stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

Your cq.select function is missing. 
Add

```
cq.select(what do you want);
```

after then

```
Root<PKEntity> root = cq.from(PKEntity.class);
```

Comment: Can you plz post the total snippet? I just want a query like select * from my entity table

Comment: cq.select(cb.array(root.get(PKEntity.column_name)); or cq.select(root) for all columns

Comment: 1. There is no columns If I use .class it's throwing me error at .get as it's not applicable

Comment: Review this link and iplement for you  https://wiki.eclipse.org//UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/Criteria#Constructors

Answer (score 0):

try adding Restriction in your criteria. Restriction is basically similar to a "Where" clause.

Comment: Solved by using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9793252/selecting-all-rows-from-a-database-using-jpa-in-websphere

Comment: Yes! Same approach with me @ benny 's answer

Comment: except that "Restriction" is part of Hibernate Criteria and the user is using JPA Criteria ...

Answer (score 0):

```
public List<Object[]> loadAllObj() {
    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Object[]> query = criteriaBuilder .createQuery(Object[].class);
    Root<PKEntity> variableRoot = query.from(PKEntity.class);
    query.select(variableRoot);
    return em.createQuery(query).getResultList();
}
```